# How to fix this RVM error on a Macbook Pro i7 Running 10.6

Tags: ruby, rvm

I received the error described on this page http://www.fakingfantastic.com/2010/11/26/fixing-the-you-have-to-install-development-tools-first-error-with-nokogiri/ and in following their instructions i recieved the following error:

```
[2011-02-13 11:05:03]  ./configure --prefix=/Users/MYNAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136 --enable-shared  
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/Users/MYNAME/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

I thought that this : https://gist.github.com/767866 looked like an aswer but i cannot locate .rvmrc.

EDIT: i think the problem is i386. My the 1.8.2 install is x8x_64, it seems.

EDIT 2: after a bit more work i have it spitting this error out

```
[2011-02-13 11:51:05]  ./configure --prefix=/Users/MYNAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136 --enable-shared            --build=i386-apple-darwin10.6.0           --host=i386-apple-darwin10.6.0 
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking for i386-apple-darwin10.6.0-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for i386-apple-darwin10.6.0-g++... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin10.6.0-c++... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin10.6.0-gpp... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin10.6.0-aCC... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin10.6.0-CC... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin10.6.0-cxx... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin10.6.0-cc++... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin10.6.0-cl.exe... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin10.6.0-FCC... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin10.6.0-KCC... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin10.6.0-RCC... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin10.6.0-xlC_r... no
checking for i386-apple-darwin10.6.0-xlC... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: in `/Users/MYNAME/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136':
configure: error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
[2011-02-13 11:58:36]  ./configure --prefix=/Users/MYNAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136 --enable-shared  
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin10.6.0
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/Users/MYNAME/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p136':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: it says no for x86_64 AND i386 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@eggie5 said:

> I would put in your os x cd and install xcode again.

Do NOT install XCode from the DVD. The version that came on the 10.6 (Snow Leopard) disk is known to be buggy. Install the latest version from [Apple's XCode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/xcode.html) site. You have to be registered to download, but it's a free registration.

I suspect you upgraded to 10.6, rather than it being installed by default when you bought your machine. 10.6 is 64-bit as is its related XCode version, so everything should have been 64-bit clean. Since it isn't it smells like regular Leopard or a pre-10.6 OS. That means all RVM hosted Rubies are suspicious and need to be cleaned up, along with any gems that were compiled prior to the upgrade and update of XCode.

After installing the XCode distribution, you'll need to uninstall, then install your RVM hosted Rubies. First, update RVM to the latest rev: Type `rvm -v` and note the revision number. Type `rvm get head` to load the latest version. When it has finished loading you should see a new revision number. RVM changes fast so you want to update to the latest pretty regularly.

This is from the [RVM FAQ](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/support/faq/) which is very good information for working with RVM, especially the comments about using `sudo` with gems:

> My ruby is compiling as 32 bit but I am on Mac OS X Snow Leopard which has heavy advertisement that it is 64 bit!!!
>
> RVM compiles to your current running kernel's architecture. This means that if your kernel is running as a 32 bit kernel (uname -m) it will compile 32 bit. You can override this behavior by placing the following in your ~/.rvmrc before installing the ruby interpreter:
>
> rvm_archflags="-arch x86_64"

I think it's a good idea to set that rather than rely on defaults, since you're probably going to be on 64-bit from now on.

Type `rvm reload` or close your terminal window and reopen a session.

Type `rvm notes` and read it. This gives you a list of prerequisites you need for a smooth install of Ruby, based on your operating system. Failure to install those means various features might not work in Ruby, which will result in random, weird failures.

Type `rvm list` and make note of your installed Ruby versions. Pretend your first one is `ruby-1.8.7-p330`. Type:

```
rvm uninstall ruby-1.8.7-p330
rvm install ruby-1.8.7-p330
```

Repeat for each one you have installed. When you are done type `rvm info` and see if what it says passes sanity checks.

If everything looks good, it's time to rebuild the native drivers for your gems.

Both of these steps are optional, but are part of a good periodic house-keeping:

- You might want to give your gems an update if you haven't run `gem update` for a while. `rvm ruby 'gem update'` will walk through the installed Rubies, updating them.
- People accumulate old gems but often don't clean them up, so, to speed up rebuilding your gems you probably should clean out your old ones. You'll have to pay attention to what its telling you as it processes, because it will let you know about dependencies that will not be met. `rvm ruby 'gem clean'` will walk through the installed Rubies, and clean out the old stuff.

To rebuild the native drivers type `rvm ruby 'gem pristine --all'`, which will reinstall all your gems.

Afterward, run `rvm info` and make sure it's returning sane information again.

Also, as an emergency escape hatch, it's entirely safe to blow away your `~/.rvm` directory, either by typing `rm -f ~/.rvm` or using `rvm implode`, then starting over. Reinstalling a Ruby is the longest part of the process, and RVM makes it pretty painless once the supporting libraries are there.

Comment: well, that was thorough. I am already in the process of downloading xcode as i took eggie's suggestion to mean "reinstall xcode." many thanks. ( if this works, i will certainly accept!)

Comment: Heh, well, I've been using RVM a while on Macs and several Linux distros and screwed myself up several times. :-) Downloading and reinstalling XCode is definitely the longest part of the process. Take your time, read all the prompts, and you should be fine since you already had a working install. Also, the author of RVM is very responsive to questions; You can get his email address from `rvm -v`.

Comment: it seems like something might be out of my control, but now i get `'Error running  ./configure --prefix=/Users/MYNAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136 --enable-shared            --build=x86_64-apple-darwin10.6.0           --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10.6.0', please read /Users/MYNAME/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p136/configure.log
'` when i try to install any version of ruby

Comment: And what does "please read /Users/MYNAME/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p136/configure.log" tell you?

Answer (score -1):

I would put in your os x cd and install xcode again.

Comment: XCode that came on the 10.6 DVD is known to be buggy. It needs to be installed/updated using the version from Apple's XCode site.